# MongoDB RelicaSet is in state RS_DOWN and InterruptedDueToReplStateChange Exception

Tags: mongodb

We setup a mongodb replica set with 3 nodes (version 3.6). Now We're having this exception thrown by the mongodb client application:

```
 << ErrorHandlerProcessor >> Query failed with error code 96 and error message 'Executor error during find command: InterruptedDueToReplStateChange: operation was interrupted' on server mongodb-0.mongodb-internal.dp-common-database.svc.cluster.local:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 96 and error message 'Executor error during find command: InterruptedDueToReplStateChange: operation was interrupted' on server mongodb-0.mongodb-internal.dp-common-database.svc.cluster.local:27017
```

After checking the mongodb server logs, we noticed that it elected a new primary due to some reasons at that time, but we cannot find out any errors. Can anyone help point me the cause or how to troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks.

And below is the mongodb logs from 2 nodes for that particular period:

---

mongodb-0

2020-09-30T06:19:32.238+0000 I NETWORK  [conn38321] end connection 172.28.42.10:58362 (115 connections now open)

2020-09-30T06:40:15.730+0000 I COMMAND  [PeriodicTaskRunner] task: UnusedLockCleaner took: 259ms

2020-09-30T06:40:15.757+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38197] command admin.$cmd command: isMaster { ismaster: 1, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:793 locks:{} protocol:op_msg 107ms

2020-09-30T06:40:15.849+0000 I REPL     [replexec-2645] Member mongodb-1.mongodb-internal.dp-common-database.svc.cluster.local:27017 is now in state RS_DOWN

2020-09-30T06:40:15.854+0000 I REPL     [replexec-2645] Member mongodb-2.mongodb-internal.dp-common-database.svc.cluster.local:27017 is now in state RS_DOWN

2020-09-30T06:40:15.854+0000 I REPL     [replexec-2645] can't see a majority of the set, relinquishing primary

2020-09-30T06:40:15.854+0000 I REPL     [replexec-2645] Stepping down from primary in response to heartbeat

2020-09-30T06:40:15.865+0000 I REPL     [replexec-2648] Member mongodb-2.mongodb-internal.dp-common-database.svc.cluster.local:27017 is now in state SECONDARY

2020-09-30T06:40:15.873+0000 I REPL     [replexec-2649] Member mongodb-1.mongodb-internal.dp-common-database.svc.cluster.local:27017 is now in state SECONDARY

2020-09-30T06:40:15.885+0000 E QUERY    [conn38282] Plan executor error during find command: DEAD, stats: { stage: "LIMIT", nReturned: 1, executionTimeMillisEstimate: 20, works: 1, advanced: 1, needTime: 0, needYield: 0, saveState: 0, restoreState: 0, isEOF: 1, invalidates: 0, limitAmount: 1, inputStage: { stage: "FETCH", nReturned: 1, executionTimeMillisEstimate: 20, works: 1, advanced: 1, needTime: 0, needYield: 0, saveState: 0, restoreState: 0, isEOF: 0, invalidates: 0, docsExamined: 1, alreadyHasObj: 0, inputStage: { stage: "IXSCAN", nReturned: 1, executionTimeMillisEstimate: 20, works: 1, advanced: 1, needTime: 0, needYield: 0, saveState: 0, restoreState: 0, isEOF: 0, invalidates: 0, keyPattern: { consumer: 1.0, channel: 1.0, externalTransactionId: -1.0 }, indexName: "lastsequence", isMultiKey: false, multiKeyPaths: { consumer: [], channel: [], externalTransactionId: [] }, isUnique: false, isSparse: false, isPartial: false, indexVersion: 2, direction: "forward", indexBounds: { consumer: [ "["som", "som"]" ], channel: [ "["normalChannelMobile", "normalChannelMobile"]" ], externalTransactionId: [ "[MaxKey, MinKey]" ] }, keysExamined: 1, seeks: 1, dupsTested: 0, dupsDropped: 0, seenInvalidated: 0 } } }

2020-09-30T06:40:15.887+0000 I REPL     [replexec-2645] transition to SECONDARY from PRIMARY

---

mongodb-1

September 30th 2020, 14:38:40.871    2020-09-30T06:38:40.871+0000 I REPL     [replication-343] Canceling oplog query due to OplogQueryMetadata. We have to choose a new sync source. Current source: mongodb-0.mongodb-internal.dp-common-database.svc.cluster.local:27017, OpTime { ts: Timestamp(1601448015, 5), t: 19 }, its sync source index:-1

2020-09-30T06:38:40.871+0000 I REPL     [replication-343] Choosing new sync source because our current sync source, mongodb-0.mongodb-internal.dp-common-database.svc.cluster.local:27017, has an OpTime ({ ts: Timestamp(1601448015, 5), t: 19 }) which is not ahead of ours ({ ts: Timestamp(1601448015, 5), t: 19 }), it does not have a sync source, and it's not the primary (sync source does not know the primary)

[replexec-7147] Starting an election, since we've seen no PRIMARY in the past 10000ms